# Source and target share the same interface MapStruct

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

Hello I have the following problem using **MapStruct**, I have the next interfaces:

```
public interface IRole {
    String getName();        
    void setName(String name);
}

public interface IUser {
    public String getUsername();
    public void setUsername(String username);
    public IRole getRole();
    public void setRole(IRole role);
    public String getPassword();
    public void setPassword(String password);
}
```

I have two implementations of both:

**User**,**UserDto**,**Role** and **RoleDto**.

I created a Mapper named UserMapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserDto userToUserDto(User user);

    RoleDto roleToRoleDto(Role user);

}
```

The problem is that when I try to transform a User to a UserDto, the role object is not transformed, I'm executing the next main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserMapper instance = Mappers.getMapper( UserMapper.class );
    Role r=new Role();
    r.setName("Admin");
    User user=new User();
    user.setUsername("Alex");
    user.setPassword("Raidentrance123");
    user.setRole(r);
    UserDto dto=instance.userToUserDto(user);
    System.out.println(dto.getUsername());      
    System.out.println(dto.getRole().getClass());       
}
```

And the result is :

> Alex class com.raidentrance.model.Role

and I expected

> Alex class com.raidentrance.model.RoleDto

Here is my question detailed [Source and target share the same interface MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329909/source-and-target-share-the-same-interface-mapstruct)

[Here is my code](https://github.com/alejandro-neology/mapstruct-issue) I'm not sure if there is something like in Jackson the **@JsonDeserialize(as=Impl.class)** or in JPA the **targetEntity**

Note: I have a solution in the branch works in the github repository. There I changed the datatype for  getRole from `IRole getRole()` to `RoleDto getRole()` and It works, but I'm looking for something like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a mapping method for the interface:

`RoleDto roleToRoleDto(IRole role);`

So mapstruct now can do a mapping, if a method returns an IRole-interface.